# Refreshing datatable binded to a datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, windows

I went through a lot of questions and solutions, can't get this to work.
I have a table on my raspberry pi which I an accessing on a windows application, the pi updates the table every second and I need the data grid to refresh itself while allowing the user control over the grid view.
I am getting a cross-thread error with this solution

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    bs.DataSource = GetAccList();//GetAccList returns a datatable  
    dataGridView1.DataSource = GetAccList();
    Loop();
} 
private void Loop()
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(2000);
    this.backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new  System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker1_DoWork);       

}
private void Refresh()
{
    while (true)
    {
       dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }
}
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Refresh();
}
```

Comment: You will need to invoke dataGridView1. Look into `Control.Invoke()`

Comment: Also, look into using async/await rather than background workers if it's easily changable and not part of a bigger platform, can make code a lot cleaner.